# error running firebase email invite code

Tags: android, firebase

I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgpJt.png) when I run my code

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Comment: please show us the app gradle file

Comment: It would be easier to review if you include code as text rather then an image. Have you tried to follow the advice to update the `google-services plugin`? Also, have you tried to fix the warnings in your build.gradle (highlighted in yellow), looks like some dependencies should be updated.